# expand-div-to-take-remaining-width - change order

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do what showed in the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/A8zLY/5/
but the order of the divs shuold be opposite, I need the left div first (I need the div with the role   `width:auto;` to be first):

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Comment: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/A8zLY/823/) like this

Comment: why do you do a float:left; if you want a div to be in the right?!

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes I think (Eyal correct me if I am wrong as it isn't clear in your question) the OP means he wants the same layout as the fiddle he linked with the order of divs changed in the markup. In your example the layout isn't the same (blue and red blocks are the other way around)

Comment: I guess I did not explain it well. I need the div with the role:   "width:auto;" to be first

Comment: @Eyal `width: auto;` is the default behaviour for the div element. that is why I removed that line in my answer. Does it fullfill your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve the same layout with the order of divs changed in the markup is to use absolute positioning :

```css
.container {
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid;
    position:relative;
}
.left {
    margin-left:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
}
.right {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change .right class float:left to float:right

code: 
.right{float:right;}